# Render contents of an object based on properties of another object JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have two object arrays. One contains an array of images and also some tags. The other is a representation of all possible tags and a boolean which decides if they will be rendered on the page or not.

```js
images = [{
  tag: ['Dog Pictures', 'Cat Pictures'],
  photos: ...
},
{
  tag: ['Lizard Pictures'],
  photos: ...
}]

filters = [
  { tag: 'Dog Pictures', render: true },
  { tag: 'Cat Pictures', render: false },
  { tag: 'Lizard Pictures', render: false }
]
```

How do I go about removing all the elements in the `images` array that have a corresponding `render` value of `false`? Keep in mind certain image elements can have various tags, but if one is set as true then I still want its element in the final result.

```js
// Desired result
result = [
  {
    tag: ['Dog Pictures', 'Cat Pictures'],
    images: ...
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter()` method

```js
const images = [{
  tag: ['Dog Pictures', 'Cat Pictures'],
},
{
  tag: ['Lizard Pictures'],
}]

const filters = [
  { tag: 'Dog Pictures', render: true },
  { tag: 'Cat Pictures', render: false },
  { tag: 'Lizard Pictures', render: false }
]

const tagsToRender = new Set(filters.filter(x => x.render).map(x => x.tag));
const imagesToRender = images.filter(img => img.tag.some(tag => tagsToRender.has(tag)))
console.log(imagesToRender)
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed. I tried using the `filter()` function but didn't think of using it this way. Thank you so much!!